# What format do games on google play store have to be in?

Tags: google-play

wanted to get started developing on the google play store or something similar (whatever is most profitable and most c# friendly, java worst case scenario) as I have made 2D games before and 1 and a bit 3D games, the problem is the signup fee, as I live in a 3rd world country and am still in high school $25 dollars is a lot of money to pay. I'm willing to do it once I've developed a game that's in a format compatible with google play, I don't know what languages or engine or file extensions are viable though.
A) What format/engine/language do they have to be in?
B) Are there C# compatible ones?

Any help apreciated.

Comment: I think you should do your homework first, and learn how to program and you will be able to answer theses questions, before thinking of publishing a game....

Comment: "learn how to program" I've just said that I've coded games before, I heard america's literacy level was bad :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since Google Play is for Android platforms I'm guessing they have to be in .apk which is Java (I'm afraid). There are some ways to compile C# code into .apk packages, but I think it's not as simple to do as it would be with Java. Check out http://xamarin.com/platform and see if it helps you in any way.

Comment: Downloaded IntelliJ, java was my first language but only used NetBeans, quick learner though. Do I need special sdks? When I make a new android project (the hello world) it warns me that I haven't added any sdks and is thus useless

Comment: Yes you need Android SDK. When I developed Android Apps (a few years ago) I used Eclipse because it had a nice plugin for Android development. If you'd rather use IntelliJ https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/prerequisites-for-android-development.html here is their guide to installing Android SDK, but I don't really know if or how it is integrated in their IDE.